# Download files with system.net.downloadfile, Path (first para) has illegal characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
var request = new WebClient();
request.DownloadFile("http://2nditeration.ca/Images/facebook.png", "C:\tmp\filename.png");
```

The first parameter is saying there are illegal characters for Path? any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing

```
"C:\tmp\filename.png"
```

to

```
@"C:\tmp\filename.png"
```

The `\` character introduces an [escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).  `\t` is a tab and `\f` is a formfeed.

The `@` tells the compiler to ignore any escape sequences in the following string.

Alternatively, you could use `\\` everywhere you actually want `\`, like

```
"C:\\tmp\\filename.png"
```